# Onclick add/delete data from datalist in localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage, html-datalist

How to add/delete data from datalist via jquery with add and delete button?
Will it also be possible to store datalist in localstorage?

*The reason behind this is that its going to be per-user-input-datalist.
much like "type it once and store it"

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Barmar, this should get me some idea to start.

Comment: @Barmar I have this so far [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/115Lsk7L/5/), I got to where it adds to the list but when I refresh the list disappears, any advise?

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else wants to accomplish the same method, Here's how I manage to pull this off: (if there's a better or efficient way please share it :)

```
var datarray = [];

function deldata() {
  // retrieve stored data (JSON stringified) and convert
  var storedData = localStorage.getItem("list_data_key");
  if (storedData) {
    datarray = JSON.parse(storedData);
  }
  var titleValue = document.getElementById('listxt').value;
  // Find and remove item from an array
  var i = datarray.indexOf(titleValue);
  if (i > -1) {
    datarray.splice(i, 1);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("list_data_key", JSON.stringify(datarray));
  datapost();
  show();

  $('#listxt').val('');
}

function insert() {
  var titleValue = document.getElementById('listxt').value;
  datarray[datarray.length] = titleValue;
  // store array to localstorage
  localStorage.setItem("list_data_key", JSON.stringify(datarray));
    show();
  $('#listxt').val('');
}

function show() {
  var content = "<b>All Elements of the Arrays :</b><br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < datarray.length; i++) {
    content += datarray[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
  datapost();
}

function datapost() {
  var options = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < datarray.length; i++)
    options += '<option value="' + datarray[i] + '" />';
  document.getElementById('bankit').innerHTML = options;
}

$(window).load(function() {
  // retrieve stored data (JSON stringified) and convert
  var storedData = localStorage.getItem("list_data_key");
  if (storedData) {
    datarray = JSON.parse(storedData);
  }
  show();
  datapost();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/115Lsk7L/36/)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use jQuery click functions and localStorage.setItem() along with localStorage.removeItem(), here's a link with more information on webstorage if you're interested...
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**HTML:**

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");
});

$('#delete').click(function() {
  localStorage.removeItem("foo");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @iPzard, I combined all the info I received and got this to work so far [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/JCprog/115Lsk7L/5/) but seems like the list disappears when I refresh the browser.